# How to pass parameters between forms in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 2-step registration process which consists of 2 different HTML pages.
The second (and final) step collects all the data and sends it to the server for evaluation. For simplicity, let's say I collect user's name in the first form and user's age in the second:

formA.html:

```
<form action="formb.html" method="get">
      Name: <input id="age" type="text" name="age">
      <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="CONTINUE">
</form>
```

formB.html:

```
<form action="serverscript.py" method="post">
      Age: <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
      <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

How can I "propagate" the "name" that user has entered in *formA.html* to *formB.html* so that I can send name,age to the server?

p.s. The only way I can thinkg is doing it with  and then parsing the URL in formB , but that seems very ugly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

formA.html:

```
 <form action="formb.html" method="get">
          Name: <input id="Name" type="text" name="Name">
          <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="CONTINUE">
    </form>
```

In form B make This Changes...

formB.html:

```
<form action="serverscript.py" method="post">
      Age: <input id="age" type="text" name="age">
      <input id="Name" type="hidden" value="">
      <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var Field=query.split("=");
    document.getElementById("Name").value = Field[1];
</script>
```

Hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 ways :

1) cookie. store the information in a cookie and read it in the second form
2) Query string.You can chain the the data to query string and read it on form B
3) You can use the `action` attribute of a form which can take a url. (recommended)

Comment: Thanks @Royi, can you explain what do you mean in (3)?

Answer (score 1):

You can build the data you get from form A as html hidden input fields within form B on load, since you are sending your data through 'GET' method, then when you submit form B, the data will be sent to the server.

**Edit**

Assuming am using PHP as server side :

forma.php

```
<form action="formb.php" method="get">
      Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
      <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="CONTINUE">
</form>
```

formb.php

```
<form action="postPage.php" method="post">
      Age: <input id="age" type="text" name="age">

      <?php
        if(isset($_GET['name'])
        {
      ?>

         <input id="name" type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']?>"/>

      <?php } ?>

      <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @KAD, this is what I thought, to build it as hidden data. However, I dont know to collect this data. Should I parse the URL???

Comment: Collecting the data depends on the server side language you are using, if it is PHP, you can use $_GET array to get the data and make a loop to build the hidden fields in the form. You can encode the URL for security then decode it in form B page.

Comment: i am using Python (but that dies not really matter). I am collecting data after the SUBMIT on formB. However, I need to propogate the data formA--->formB and there is no server side involved in that process. The only way I can thinkg is doing it with methid-get on form A and then parsing the URL in formB , but that seems ugly...

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it clear for you, I don't know if it can be applied the same in Python though.

Comment: I saw, thatnk for replying. However, this still involves a server side request and I am sure it can be done without server involved (e.g. parsing the URL, but as I saidm it seems ugly to me), so I am looking for a more "elegant" way to pass params between forms...

Comment: why don;t you handle it using javascript, you can use a single form and handle fields visibility based on user input

Comment: I cant use 1 form, since this is a 2-step acquisition process. I must use 2 different pages and 2 different pages and can not put everything in 1 fimr :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81734/discussion-between-kad-and-yura).

Answer (score 1):

Try using HTML5 sessionStorage to store data in browser session. During the session, a user could visit other pages of the domain, or other sites entirely, then return to the original domain. Any data saved in sessionStorage during that session will remain available, but only to pages in the original domain, until the tab or window is closed.